# Referencing a java project from a Spring boot Web Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am adding a java project(Project A) to a Spring boot Maven project(Project B) in eclipse but Prject B could not find the beans of Project A.
Then I added the ScanBasePackages for Project A in Project B as below

`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "net.abc.A", "net.abc.B" })
 public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}`

But now this is not scanning the controller and mapping with url in project B.
Earlier without adding project A it was working correctly.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try defining a configuration file using `@Configuration` and placing `@ComponentScan("net.abc")` along with it in your project B. Note that `net.abc` should be a base package of where your class is defined (assuming you have registered it as a bean)

Comment: HI @Sibtain, Actullay SpringBootApplication in itself contain all these annotation and i have already provided them in SpringBootApplication as shown in the code snippet above. Now it can find beans of project A but now it can't find its own controller and all url giving 404 not found.